# Pass HashMap with Custom Parcelable Arraylist between activities

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, parcelable

I am trying to pass the HashMap between between my services and activity. I know how to pass Arraylist with custom objects.
But failed to find the solutions for passing hashmap from service.

I have service from where I want to send hashMap to my activity

```
   public void getpProperies(ArrayList<property> values){
    if(values != null && values.size() > 0){
        for(property si : values){
            if(si instanceof esOtherProperty){
                Log.d(TAG, "Data "+ ((esOtherProperty) si).name);

            }
            if(si instanceof esEmpProperty){
                Log.d(TAG, "EMP Data "+ ((esEmpProperty) sig).name);
            }
        }
    }

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("si", allvalues);
    if(resultReceiver != null)
    resultReceiver.send(100,bundle);
}
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<esProperty>> allvalues;
```

so instead bundle.putParcelableArrayList("si", allvalues), is there any way to pass allvalues hashmap. I looked in Bundle Class but did not find anything.

Comment: how about `putSerializable()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**putParcelableArrayList()** takes in an ArrayList<"Parcable Items">, not a HashMap. Since HashMaps and ArrayLists are Serializable, **putSerializable()** should work.

Comment: but now when I am doing 
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<property>> allvalues = new HashMap<>();
                allvalues = resultData.getSerializable("si");
it fails? with incompatible types

Comment: Did you try casting it to a hashmap, something like this:
allvalues = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<esProperty>>) resultData.getSerializable("si");